# The CoolTerm can not find the `/dev/tty.wchusbserial1410`

Tags: macos

I insert the serial-USB convertor into my Mac.

and in the `/dev`, there is `tty.wchusbserial1410`.

I use the [CoolTerm](http://freeware.the-meiers.org/) as the software for manage the connect.

but in the Serial Port Options, there can not find the `tty.wchusbserial1410`:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

there is only shows the `cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port`.

---

**EIDIT-01**

Now, I connected the wchusbserial, but there is blank.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: just give a click on the button “Re-Scan Serial Ports”, it should find out your device if it is really connected with a good cable on your computer. If still not working, yur board could be broken. Be prepared to have some other checking methods/instruments, like an oscilloscope.

Comment: @Yoan Now, there shows the `tty.wchusbserial1410`, but the connect is blank.

Comment: You are right, the actual version is 1.5.0. As for connection, go back to the connection properties and disable all hardware handshaking (RTS, DTR) - shows enabled in your picture. Usually the protocol is simple serial, no handshaking. Also, the serial speed must be as prescribed for your device.